# magit-define-popup-option not found

Tags: emacs, magit

At some point I managed to add an option to the magit pull popup.

This line ended up in my .emacs (which I believe worked at some point):

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-pull-popup
  ?s "recurse submodules" "--recurse-submodules=yes")
```

Now I get:

```
eval: Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-define-popup-option
```

The call looks correct to me according to:
https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Additional-proposed-infix-arguments-and-suffix-commands

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-commit-popup
  ?D "Override the author date" "--date=" #'read-from-minibuffer)
```

Comment: What did you change in your environment recently? new version of emacs?

Comment: Is magit definitely loaded before you run that?  Does it work if you `(require 'magit-popup)` before?

Comment: @jpkotta this is the correct answer (I added the line of code in my .emacs when I first came up with the setting interactively - it never actually worked on start up but I leave emacs open long enough to forget!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function before it has been defined.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "magit-commit"
  (magit-define-popup-option 'magit-commit-popup
    ?D "Override the author date" "--date=" #'read-from-minibuffer))
```

n.b. `"magit-popup"` is the library which defines the `magit-define-popup-option` function, but I am assuming you want to do this only after `"magit-commit"` has been loaded (at which point the popup you are specifically interested in has been defined).

Comment: You are correct, but as jpkotta pointed out, it's simply that I hadn't loaded magit yet.

Comment: Yes -- that's exactly the same problem that this solution resolves, but this way you don't *have* to load Magit in order to configure it; you simply say "if at any point I *do* load it, then also do this".